# If $(a-b)x^2+ax+1=0$ has two real roots $l , m$ such that $l=2m$ What is the maximum value of $b$ satisfying that?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $(a-b)x^2+ax+1=0$  has two real roots  $l , m$  such that  $l=2m$
>   What is the maximum value of $b$ satisfying that ?

I need help with this question please,  a hint to go

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**  In the light of the hint by @dxiv (thanks to him) I complete the solution:

> $a^2 - 3 a^2+9(a-b)=0$
>   $-2a^2+9a-9b=0$
>   $2a^2-9a+9b=0$
>   $\implies$ Discriminant =$ 81-4 (2)(9b)>0$
>   $\iff b <\frac {81}{72}=\frac {9}{8}$

DONE

Comment: Hint: $(a-b)x^2+ax+1 = (a-b)(x-l)(x-m)$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $a \ne b$ for the equation to have two roots, then by Vieta's formulas $\displaystyle\frac{-a}{a-b}=l+m=3m\,$, so $\displaystyle\frac{-a}{3(a-b)}$ must be a root:

$$\require{cancel}
\bcancel{(a-b)}\cdot \frac{a^2}{9(a-b)^\bcancel{2}} - a \cdot \frac{a}{3(a-b)} + 1 = 0 \;\;\iff\;\; a^2 - 3 a^2+9(a-b)=0
$$

Comment: is the final answer     $ \frac {81}{72}$    ?

Comment: Right, same as $\,\frac{9}{8}\,$.